# Mysql Date Issue

Tags: php, mysql

In my MySQL server, I have rows that have the date of my created content.
Example: 2013-03-17 02:53:47

For now, I am using:

```
$date = $fetch[thedaterownamegoeshere];

<?php echo $date; ?>
```

But instead of getting the full content of the date (2013-03-17 02:53:47), I'd like to get only the date – in this example, I wish to have the number "2013-03-17" as the result. How can I do that?

Comment: In MySQL, you can use the `Date()` function. In PHP (application code), you can use the combination of `date` and `strtotime` functions.

Answer (score 2):

when fetching put the value into the date function provided by PHP
e.g.

```
$format = 'Y-m-d';
$timestr = strtotime($fetch[thedaterownamegoeshere]);
$date = date($format, $timestr);
```

Make sure your $fetch returns a string like "2013-03-17 02:53:47"

The format can be formatted in your way. Check http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php for a detailed description. the separators can be changed as well to your preferences, for now, I just set it to ':'.

And of course you can do it shorter like this;

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', $fetch[thedaterownamegoeshere]);
```

I hope this helped you out

Comment: I will modify my code for that, like i said he can just adjust the : to - in my explenation

Answer (score 1):

you can use DATE function in mysql  and in your example you can use it like

```
select DATE(thedaterownamegoeshere) from your_table_name
```

and also check mysql date  document

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

Answer (score 0):

```html
  I hope this helped you..
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fetch[thedaterownamegoeshere]));
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks